# rust ndarray cumulative product/sum

Tags: numpy, math, rust, vectorization, rust-ndarray

I am learning the rust language and working with the ndarray crate. Could someone explain to me how to apply cumulative functions to an ndarray?

As example it would be great to see how to get a cumulative product of an ndarray.
I could not manage to find any higher level function [here](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#methods-for-all-array-types)  for this, like numpy offers `numpy.cumprod()`

I came up whith this, is there a faster/better way in rust with ndarray, can vectorization be used for cumulative functions?

```
let some_valuesvalues = Array1::from(vec![2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]);
let cumulative_products: Array1<f64> = some_values
.iter()
.scan(1.0, |acc, &x| {
    *acc *= x;
    Some(*acc)
})
.collect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit in packing the vector into an `Array1` beforehand. You can do this after the calculation.
If you already have an `Array1` convert it to the inner vector with `to_vec()`.
You can reuse the vector `some_values` to store the `cumulative_products` results:

```
let mut some_values = vec![2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0];
let cumulative_products = &mut some_values[..];
let mut last = 1_f64;
for i in 0..cumulative_products.len() {
    last *= cumulative_products[i];
    cumulative_products[i] = last;
}
```

gets: `[2.0, 6.0, 24.0, 120.0]`

Comment: is there no benefit in using ndarray for this, like faster indexing better memory footprint or something else? are the iter() and scan() methodsvstd lib features and no performance adjusted ndarray specifc methods?

Comment: There is a rich table of safe conversions from the arrays back to the `Vec`s/slices/scalars. These can be used for faster solutions. The `ndarray` functions make working with the arrays more convenient, but not faster.

Comment: okay but for other arythmetics like multiplication, ndarray offers blast suppoert, I guess thi then would make sense to use ndarray for right? but for other operations like indexing or insertions it does not? could you comment on that please

Comment: This is mostly a matter of taste. Your question was about speed. In this specific case, allocating a new vector takes the most time. Whenever speed is required you can directly access the wrapped vector/scalar. But that doesn't mean you have to do without the `ndarray` functions.

Comment: If you have a lot of math to do, you might be better served with the **nalgebra** crate.